# Show the following function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $ f $ be defined by $f(x)=x$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$.

I think it's obvious that it's continuous but maybe it still needs to be shown. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show continuity at $x = 0$. Now since $f(0) = 0$, $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x) = \lim \limits_{x\to 0^{-}} 0 = 0$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = \lim \limits_{x\to 0^{+}} x = 0$, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to use $\varepsilon- \delta$ language, just note that $|f(x)-0| = |x-0| <\delta = \varepsilon $, and on LHS $|0-0|=0$, so $\delta$ is arbitrary.